# How to yank text to search command (after "/") in evil-mode?

Tags: evil, search, yank

Is it there any way to yank in the search command (after press "/") in evil-mode?

Answer (score 1):

```
(defadvice evil-search-forward (after evil-search-forward-after-hack activate)
  (if (and isearch-string
           (> (length isearch-string) 0)
           (not (string= isearch-string (format "%s" (car kill-ring)))))
           (kill-new isearch-string)))
```

BTW, the regex is also automatically inserted into `evil-search-forward-history`.